# What is the correct (most Laravel) approach to this probem (if any)

Tags: php, laravel, type-hinting

In my application I have a model named 'Order' like this, following the default Laravel behavior, and with an additional unique string property named 'hash':

```
class Order extends Model {
  // $table = 'orders'; 
  // $primaryKey = 'id';
  // $incrementing = true;
  $hash = 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9';

  // many related models
}
```

The default behavior of function Model::find is to look for the primary key which is a feature I definitely want to keep. Currently my routes/api.php contains functions like this:

```
public function show(Request $request, Order $order) {
  // the order will be loaded via the id
  // if the model is not found an exception is thrown
}
```

On some occasions I would now like to inject the same order but searched via the order's hash, so I assume my api.php would look something like this:

```
public function show(Request $request, OrderSearchByHash $order) {
  // the order will be loaded via the id
  // if the model is not found an exception is thrown
}
```

And here comes the question: is this achievable and if yes, how? I don't actually need the source code for that but a hint to the direction I have to go to. I've already read about ServiceProviders and Facades, tried creating an extended model (but I would have to "patch" all relations because the pivot tables would have a different name) and many other stuff on the Laravel documentation but I still don't even know exactly if and what covers my specific problem?

Has anybody a hint for me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Why should the `show` method know whether the order was searched through an ID or a hash? What difference would it make?

Comment: As far as I understood the documentation (and I may be complete off topic in that case) the service provider recognizes through type hinting what model I request and loads it for me.
What I want it to do is still look for an order model but not via the ID but the hash.


What I expect is to change only the injected type in my controller, retrieve the exact same model as I would when searching via the ID, and continue with the same source code I currently use.

Comment: Yes, but in both cases, your controller method should receive an `Order`. The way to obtain it shouldn't change its type. What you probably want to do is change how the route to that controller method is constructed, something like `route('show', [Order::firstWhere('hash', $hash)])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom Model binding :

Both your method in your controller will look like this:

```
public function show(Request $request, Order $order) {
 
}
```

```php
Route::get('orders/{order}', 'OrderController@show');
Route::get('orders-by-hash/{order_by_hash}', 'OrderController@show');
```

```php
Route::bind('order_by_hash', function ($value) {
// Use your logic for finding your order by hash
            return Order::where[...]->first();
});
```

you can also authorise to find an order by ID only when you are connected :

```
Route::bind('order', function ($value) {
// Use your logic for finding your order by hash
            return Order::where[...]->when(auth()->check(), function()
               $query->orWhere(function($query){
                      $query->where(order_id, $value)
                            ->where(user_id, auth()->id());
                })
)->first();
});
```

```
So when you are connected, IF an order with the id belongs to the user , you can find it that way

This is only relevant if your route using an id and your hash are using the same controller's methods, else I recommend to use 2 different model bindings
```

Comment: That would be a viable solution for one route but I forgot to mention that the order model is used in at least twenty routes and I would have to change every one of them. That's one of the reason I would like to change the injection, I hoped it'd be the easiest (and most laravel way)

Comment: this is the list laravel way, because if you use the same route model name ({order}) then either using the id or the hash would give you a model and I think that your hash is supposeto obfuscate the id of your order so people could not juste find it with orders/1, so the easiest way it having routes for an internal usage using {order} (when you are logged in, so you can check if you can access an order) and route for your public access using {order_by_hash}. You can also always always use your hashed route but IF you are connected, then you can find it with ID, I will edit my answer to show it

Comment: do I get this correctly that Route::bind changes the way that variables named {order} in any URL are interpreted? and that's how I could decide to either search for the model via the primaryKey or the hash?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a condition where the `{id}` is PK or hash. And then, perform a query according to the type of `{id}` obtained.

For example :

```php
Route::get('orders/{id}', [OrderController::class, 'show']);
```

```php
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $type = ctype_alnum($id) ? 'hash' : 'pk'; // or another checking method
    $item = $type == 'pk'
    ? Order::find($id)
    : Order::where('hash', $id)->first();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mathieu: thanks for the tip with Route::bind, I ended up with this in RouteServiceProvider

```
Route::bind('order', function($value) {
  if((int)$value > 0 && env('APP_ENV', 'production') == 'dev') {
    return Order::find($value);
  }

  return Order::where('hash', (string)$value)->first();
});
```

I allowed ID usage on dev environment so I can test the API more easily with Postman.

Again: Thank you very much!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-resolution-logic

I actually switched to use "public function resolveRouteBinding()" within the actual order model, this looks cleaner too me if I ever need a second model to use a different search key instead of it's primary key